# DropDownList SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

here is my code

ASPX Code

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="Type" DataValueField="days" 
                            onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                            Visible="False">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
                            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:prevaluesConnectionString %>" 
                            SelectCommand="select * from [plans USA] order by CAST([Type] as decimal)">
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

C#

```
protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 0;

        {

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["techconn"].ToString());

            SqlCommand com1 = new SqlCommand("select * from tech where accid0v =" + Session["update"], con);

            SqlCommand com2 = new SqlCommand("select * from techs where accid0v =" + Session["update"], con);

            SqlCommand com3 = new SqlCommand("select * from techh where accid0v =" + Session["update"], con);

            con.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader1 = com1.ExecuteReader();
            SqlDataReader reader2 = com2.ExecuteReader();
            SqlDataReader reader3 = com3.ExecuteReader();            

            if (reader1.Read())//Personal details
            {

                //Label30.Text = reader1["accid0v"].ToString();
                DropDownList1.Text = reader1["count0v"].ToString();
                TextBox12.Text = reader1["count0v"].ToString();
                DropDownList2.Text = reader1["piq0v"].ToString();
                TextBox1.Text = reader1["billin0v"].ToString();
                TextBox2.Text = reader1["fcustn0v"].ToString();
                TextBox3.Text = reader1["lcustn0v"].ToString();
                TextBox4.Text = reader1["contph0v"].ToString();
                TextBox5.Text = reader1["email0v"].ToString();
                TextBox6.Text = reader1["altph0v"].ToString();
                TextBox7.Text = reader1["pass0v"].ToString();               

            }

            if (reader2.Read())//Subscription Details
            {

                DropDownList3.Text = reader2["subst0v"].ToString();
                TextBox8.Text = reader2["actd0v"].ToString();
                TextBox9.Text = reader2["expir0v"].ToString();
                TextBox10.Text = reader2["pric0v"].ToString();
                TextBox11.Text = reader2["subst0v"].ToString();

                DateTime today = new DateTime();                    
                today = System.DateTime.Now;

                DateTime exp = new DateTime();
                exp = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox9.Text);

                TimeSpan ts = exp.Subtract(today).Duration();


                TextBox20.Text = ts.Days.ToString();

                if(ts.TotalDays<=0)
                {
                    Label43.Text = "Expired";
                }
                else
                {
                    Label43.Text = "Active";
                }

            }

            if (reader3.Read())//Hardware Details
            {
                DropDownList5.Text = reader3["tof0v"].ToString();
                DropDownList6.Text = reader3["brand0v"].ToString();
                DropDownList7.Text = reader3["os0v"].ToString();
                TextBox21.Text = reader3["mac0v"].ToString();
            }

            con.Close();

        }

        {//Country check
            if ( TextBox12.Text == "us")
            {
                Label14.Text = "$";
                DropDownList3.Visible = true;
                DropDownList4.Visible = false;


                //plan name check start

                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["preconn"].ToString());

                SqlCommand com1 = new SqlCommand("select * from [plans USA] where Type ='" + TextBox10.Text + "'", con);

                con.Open();

                SqlDataReader reader1 = com1.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader1.Read())//plans check
                {
                    Label20.Text = reader1["pname"].ToString();
                }
                con.Close();//plan name check end
            }

            if (TextBox12.Text == "ca")
            {
                Label14.Text = "$";
                DropDownList3.Visible = true;
                DropDownList4.Visible = false;
            }

            else if (TextBox12.Text == "uk")
            {
                Label14.Text = "£";
                DropDownList4.Visible = true;
                DropDownList3.Visible = false;


                //plan name check start

                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["preconn"].ToString());

                SqlCommand com1 = new SqlCommand("select * from [PLANS UK] where Type ='" + TextBox10.Text + "'", con);

                con.Open();

                SqlDataReader reader1 = com1.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader1.Read())//plans check
                {
                    Label20.Text = reader1["pname"].ToString();
                }
                con.Close();//plan name check end


            }

            else
            {
            }
        }//country check end

    }
```

i an getting error

'DropDownList3' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value

i am using visual studio 2010 asp.net,SQL Server 2008

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: Are you somehow manipulating the values in the dropdown list during in your button click event so that the original values are changed? This would explain why when you are trying to set the selected value you are getting this error.

Comment: Also, I don't see where in your code you're actually setting the DropDownList's selected value.

Comment: Well, obviously this line: `DropDownList3.Text = reader2["subst0v"].ToString()` tries to set the value to something that is no in the drop down. Specifics depend on your actual data in the DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the selected item of DropDownList3 to the content of reader2 as you code:

```
DropDownList3.Text = reader2["subst0v"].ToString()
```

But you are setting this data within the DropDownList3 that is empty or doesn't have the item that you are setting using `reader2["subst0v"].ToString()`

Try to check DropDownList3.Items putting a breakpoint on this line and see if I am right.

If the DropDown is empty, check the SQL that is populating data to the control. If it's not empty, just check if there is the value equals `reader2["subst0v"].ToString()` in `DropDownList3.Items`.